# Pwm MegaWidgets do not work in destroy widgets

Tags: tkinter, tk-toolkit, pmw

I try the code below, and I receive "_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!frame.!frame.!entry"
The purpose is combobox megawidget  to appear in quake window when I press the Button

```
enter code here


  from tkinter import *

  import Pmw

  class engineer(object):

  def __init__(self,quake,parent):
     self.quake=quake
     self.parent=parent
    
  def arent(self):
    self.parent=Tk()
    self.parent.geometry('200x200')
    self.ba=Button(self.parent,text='display',command=self.combo)
    self.ba.grid()
    
def zone_define(self,a):
    print(a)

def combo(self):
    self.quake=Tk()
    self.quake.geometry('200x200')
    zone=["I", "II", "III"]
 
combobox=Pmw.ComboBox(self.quake,label_text='Play',label_bg='white',labelmargin=0,labelpos='wn',
     label_relief=FLAT,listbox_width=24,selectioncommand=self.zone_define)
     combobox.grid()
     combobox.selectitem(asply[1])
     self.quake.mainloop()
if __name__=='__main__':
    gr=engineer(None,None)
    gr.arent()
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation errors in the posted code.

Comment: Don't use `tk.Tk` more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the error is being generated due to the fact that you are defining Tk() multiple times. This creates a new window each time, which will create conflicting changes.

I had a similar error before, and I fixed it by simply removing the second Tk().

Comment: I use a Toplevel widget instead of Tk()

Answer (score 0):

Instead of TK() I try a Toplevel widget and work. I think this is a good solution
Here is the solution. Pay attention in combo function

from tkinter import *
import Pmw
class engineer(object):
def **init**(self,quake,parent):
self.quake=quake
self.parent=parent

```
def arent(self):
    self.parent=Tk()
    self.parent.geometry('200x200')
    

    self.ba=Button(self.parent,text='ana',command=self.combo)
    self.ba.grid()
    
def zone_define(self,a):
    print(a)

def combo(self):
    self.quake=Toplevel()
    self.quake.geometry('200x200')
    zone=["I", "II", "III"]
  
        
     combobox=Pmw.ComboBox(self.quake,label_text='Play',label_bg='white',
            labelmargin=0, labelpos='wn',label_relief=FLAT,
            listbox_width=24,selectioncommand=self.zone_define,
             scrolledlist_items=zone,  
            arrowbutton_bg='white',arrowbutton_relief=FLAT,
             arrowbutton_highlightcolor='white',arrowbutton_bd=0)
    combobox.grid()
    combobox.selectitem(zone[0])
    self.quake.mainloop()
if __name__=='__main__':
    gr=engineer(None,None)
    gr.arent()
```